# Refresh message after every user attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a success or failure message pop up every time the user enters input and clicks out of the input area. Here's what I currently have:

```
function checkUsername() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

    if (username.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("username_message").className = "failure";
        document.getElementById("username_message").innerHTML = "Username is too short.";
        $("#username_message").fadeOut(3000);

    } else {
        document.getElementById("username_message").className = "success";
        document.getElementById("username_message").innerHTML = "Valid!";
        $("#username_message").fadeOut(3000);
    }
```

In terms of the input field, I have the following:

```
<input type="text" id="username" onblur="checkUsername()" autofocus>
```

When I run this code and click out of the input field, the error message displays, but to get any other message to display, I have to refresh the page. The input field is currently inside a form, so I was wondering how I could get the message(s) to show every time, instead of having to refresh the page? Once one message shows, the other one doesn't unless I refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuerys `fadeOut` method will fade opacity to 0 and then set `display:none` on the element. You need to "reverse" this.

So change the function to:

```
function checkUsername() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

    if (username.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("username_message").className = "failure";
        document.getElementById("username_message").innerHTML = "Username is too short.";

    } else {
        document.getElementById("username_message").className = "success";
        document.getElementById("username_message").innerHTML = "Valid!";
    }
    $("#username_message").stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(3000);
}
```

The `.stop(true, true)` will instantly make the fadeout to end, then set the opacity back to 1. With [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5y7a61j/1/)

Comment: I'd argue that the `$("#username_message").stop(true, true).show();` would be better placed right before the `fadeOut` call (or even chained together in a single call after the whole if-else block)... Other than that this is by far the cleanest solution... deleting my own clumsy answer.

Comment: @Mikk3lRo Thanks for the editing! I just took your opinion and about to change my answer :)

Comment: My first edit on SO - perfect opportunity to try out the feature ;)

Comment: lol, and thanks again that I find out you even give a explanation on `fadeout` at the start.

Answer (score -1):

innerHTML replace everything inside use append() instead.

```
var error = '<p id="errorCode01">some error</p>'; 

// if fail test 

$('#username_message').append(error);

// if pass test get the error

$('#username_message').find('#errorCode01').remove();
```